# Decomposing a variety into irreducible components

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Suppose that $ k $ is a field of characteristic $ \neq 2. $ Decompose into irreducible components the closed set $ X \subset \mathbb{A}^{3} $ defined by $ x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} = 0, x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}+1 = 0. $

My impression is that $ V(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}) \cap V(x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}+1) = \emptyset. $

$ \emptyset $ is clearly irreducible, but I feel that I have gone horribly wrong.

Comment: Yes, you have erred. From adding the two equations, you can see that if any solutions exist, they must have $x^2=-\frac12$. What happens with the equations once you use this?

Comment: @KReiser We have that $ y^{2}+z^{2} = \frac{1}{2} $ and $ y^{2}+z^{2} = -\frac{1}{2}. $ I think that because $ \text{char}(k) \neq 2, $ only $ y^{2}+z^{2} = \frac{1}{2} $ is correct.

Comment: Check your signs again.

Comment: I see it @KReiser, just $ y^{2}+z^{2} = \frac{1}{2}. $